# Three 12v computer fans, how much voltage on my power supply do i need?

Tags: voltage

i have 3 12v computer fans and i'm not sure to use 36v ac power supply. i've only done a couple of projects before and this is my first one without complete guidance. Three 12v computer fans, how much voltage output does my ac adapter need?

Comment: If you run the fans in parallel, you need only 12V. Using the fans in series is a bad idea anyway, because if one fan fails, they will probably all fail. Mind that the current capability need to be such that your supply can feed three fans.

Comment: Computer fans are generally 12vdc, with your supply you would need to rectify, smooth and regulate it down with a buck converter before use. It's probably less work to find a 12vdc wall wart with enough current capability and use them in parallel.

Comment: Don't wire the fans in series. Each fan needs 12V **DC** /100mA. So a 12V/500mA regulator/power supply is sufficient.

Comment: You can't put DC fans in series, they have extreme current swings going from ~0mA to 100's of mA in a cycle. I suppose you could use really large capacitors to smooth this out (and then you'd still have ripple). Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you fans are of the same type, you might be lucky. Anyways you should add three zenerdiodes around 12V and three good sized electrolytic capacitors. But you should be prepared that there might be smoke.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1DgBa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Note that the OP is contemplating using an **AC** supply.

Comment: OMG, I was thinking AC supply, as in AC input. You need to rectify of you most definitely will let the smoke out.

Comment: Though this system works in theory and you might get away with it in practice, those diodes need to be able to carry the full start-up current of one, or two motors. .i.e. what happens if you stall one or two fans. If the supply is >36V that's a whole lot of current and power chugging through that chain. AS you say.. be prepared for smoke :) Probably safer to go with like 13V zeners to limit the top speed to solve the latter issue.

Comment: Right, you want to choose some beefy zehners, which are not really typical esp. for rather high voltages. It'll be a very fragile system.

Comment: 36 V AC rectified will be about 50 V DC. At that point, it would be simpler and more efficient to use a buck converter to get to 12 V DC and run the fans in parallel.

Comment: Zener are not needed as FANS are fairly linear current with voltage above start and equalize RPM and current thus voltage is balanced.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the fans will be DC not AC.

**HOWEVER:** Running DC motors in series is a bad idea.

What will actually happen is whichever fan has least drag and or best torque will run really fast and the others will stall or run much slower. You will be over-driving that one motor and will likely damage it. You can use a zener arrangement as suggested by wiebel, however those zeners need to be able to carry the full start-up current and may get very hot if one fan is struggling under a heavy load.

It is much simpler, and safer, to run the motors in parallel using a 12V supply that can deliver three times one fan's start-up current requirement.

Comment: DC fans have a far different load than other motors, so series operation is guarantee for same FANS. -1

Answer (score -1):

Imagine a gear thats about 1 foot diameter. and you have three widgets each one needs a 1 foot diameter gear in order to work. Would it make sense to buy a 3 foot diameter gear to run all three? Or would it make more sense to crank the one gear just a little bit harder to run all three?  Remember, the *requirement* for the widgets is a 1 foot gear. If you give them more than 1 foot you're going outside of the requirements you could potentially damage them.

So in this case, you're running all three widgets on a 1 foot gear, only you have to crank that gear three times as hard so all three widgets can run. That is analogous to amperage.  So the power supply needs to stay as 12 volts only it has to provide three times as much current to run all three fans and computer power supplies typically have plenty of amperage to run especially fans.