# Series or parallel fan connection

Tags: power-supply, voltage

So I wish to wire a project that uses three 12 V fans but I don't know if I should get a power supply with 12 V or 36 V.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Three 12v computer fans, how much voltage on my power supply do i need?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/309511/three-12v-computer-fans-how-much-voltage-on-my-power-supply-do-i-need)

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Although duplicate, the duplicate has false assumptions for fans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 12V and  wire the fans in parallel.

If you use a 36V power supply and wire the fans in series, the voltage might not be shared equally. This could even cause the fans to burn out.

In parallel, they will all get 12V.

Comment: Not true for BLDC identical fans -1 based only on bad assumption.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Even true for identical BLDC fans. What if one has more air resistance? There are active electronics in a BLDC fan, so it could even be more harmful than for brushed fans (which at least will take a few seconds to overheat).

Comment: then the designer is too dumb to understand balance or air flow but the one with more resistance runs at a higher RpM  since air resistance means no flow higher pressure, and less work flow done but more eddy current losses but since they share current the load still looks like a resistor.  even better, is if one fan fails to start , the other add pressure to start so it works. When they share the same air flow in or out

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine. trust me.

BLDC Fans with aerodynamic loading end up looking like a resistive Load so Voltage is divided equally guaranteed and fans run well.

I used 24V x 2 from 48V in production of 10k units , no issues for voltage , but 1% failures unrelated due to dead start from Hall sensor errors from Korean supplier.

I performed a ganged start stop test automated every 2 sec 0.3 ON 1.7 OFF and if fan failed to start from each random stop position , batch was rejected and supplier notified , which they fixed immediately.

Not ONLY did I run them in series but I regulated the output from 0 to max (46V) with a linear regulator and both fans stayed at same speed thruput the thermal feedback range from 45’C to 55’C.

I designed a custom fan regulator using NPN thermistor, R ratios and LM317 with sensing the hot spot in a 1U high 180 W PSU.

They only turned on near full load >70%. they never required full speed at room temp at full load due to my innovative spoiler high velocity turbulent cooling simple design.